# i have a file record with apache software versions, need to sort them based on version

Tags: linux, unix, awk

I have a file with data as below format,

```
File: Test.txt
org.apache.hive.v.0.3.5
org.apache.pig.v.0.2.3
org.apache.hadoop.0.1.1
org.apache.v.0.2.5
```

This record should be sorted based on the version numbers, I tried using **awk** command but unable get correct answer.what approach should i need to follow ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is just going to be ugly since the columns upon which you want to sort are only notable by their position compared to the end of the line (The last three columns) so `sort -nk<start>,<stop>` isn't going to cut it.

You could use `awk` to move those to the front of the string, then hit it with sort, then use sed to scrape those sorting fields off the front of the record:

```
awk -F"." 'BEGIN{OFS=" "}{print $(NF-2),$(NF-1),$NF,$0}' Test.txt | sort -nk1,3 | sed 's/^[0-9].*\s[0-9].*\s[0-9].*\s//g'
```

Perhaps some `sed` experts could clean that up a bit, but this should do the trick on it's own (This is assuming that version numbers are always `<number>.<number>.<number>`